# re render wipes my inputs, how do I keep them?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks

```
interface DateRangePickerDialogProps
{
    format:string;
    rangeEnabled:boolean;
    startDate:Date;
    endDate:Date;
    onAccept(startDate:Date, endDate:Date):void;
}


export function DateRangePickerDialog(props: DateRangePickerDialogProps & DialogProps)
{
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(props.startDate);
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(props.endDate);

    const onDateRangeChange = (startDate:Date, endDate:Date) =>
    {
        setStartDate(startDate);
        setEndDate(endDate);
    }

    const onAccept = () =>
    {
        props.onAccept(startDate, endDate);
        props.onHide();
        console.log(startDate, endDate)

    }

    return <Dialog {...props as DialogProps} icon={FiCalendar}>
        <DateRangePicker rangeEnabled={props.rangeEnabled} onDateRangeChange={onDateRangeChange}
            startDate={startDate} endDate={endDate} format={"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"}/>
            <button onClick={() => onDateRangeChange(startDate,endDate)}>Aceptar</button>
        {/* <MainButton className='dialog-button' label='Aceptar' onClick={onAccept} autoFocus={true} /> */}
    </Dialog>;
}
```

this is my **code** and it works almost fine, I have a calendar where i can choose Start and EndDate but when i click accept on the calendar and it hides away the days I chose seem to disapear. Any ideas how i can fix this and keep the days marked after closing/opening the calendar again? im new to hooks... :,(  im a bit lost.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your changed value in the component's state and then set it as value to input element.

[This article](https://rangle.io/blog/simplifying-controlled-inputs-with-hooks/) shows you how do update the input element using Hooks like so:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export function NameForm(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  
  const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
      evt.preventDefault();
      alert(`Submitting Name ${name}`)
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Frirst Name:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Im using hooks, so im not using any classes, thats the problem...
I have a fully funtional code done like this, but im trying to adapt it to use react hooks and im having some trouble.

Comment: @ChechesMtz I've updated the code to use hooks instead

Comment: awesome bro, thanks. Im going to try and apply it. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to move your state to a store, with a state management solution like MobX - https://mobx.js.org/README.html

MobX has a nice and easy learning curve, and is pretty intuitive.

In short, you would decorate values in your store with `@observable`:

```html
export class DateRangePickerDialogStore {
    @observable startDate = undefined;
    @observable endDate = undefined;

    @action
    resetStore = () =>< {
        this.startDate = undefined;
        this.endDate = undefined;
    }

    @action
    updateStartDate = value => {
        this.startDate = value;
    }

    @action
    updateEndDate = value => {
        this.endDate = value;
    }
}
```

and your component with `@observer`:

```html
export const DateRangePickerDialog = observer((props: DateRangePickerDialogProps & DialogProps){

...

})
```

and then you can set and retrieve values from your store by calling the `action`s, or from the stores variables. An implementation similar to this will allow your stored values to persist component rerenders.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: ill have to read a bit about mobx and see if i cn implement it. thanks ^^